# How does boolean "&" and "&&" works for bit comparison?

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic

```
PORTB = 0b11001011;
PORTC = 0b00111011;
if(PORTB & PORTC)
    {
     //do something
    }
```

//will this "if" comes out to be true?how compiler will check it?

```
PORTB = 0b11001011;
PORTC = 0b00111011;
if(PORTB && PORTC)
    {
    //do something
    }
```

//how this "&&" be compared? if i write "if(PORTB)" than how compiler wil evaluate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&` does bit and, so

```
PORTB & PORTC == 0b00001011
```

converting this to a boolean yields `true` (non-zero)

`&&` does boolean and, so `PORTB` is `true` (non-zero), and `PORTC` is `true`, so

```
PORTB && PORTC
```

yields `true`

---

So is there a difference? Yes. `&&` uses short-circuiting, while `&` doesn't. Consider the following:

```
0 & some_complicated_expression
0 && some_complicated_expression
```

In the first case, the complicated expression will be evaluated. However, since `&&` uses short-circuiting, the complicated expression is not evaluated in the second case (the expression yields `false`, irrespective of the result of the complicated expression).

Comment: @huester
so if i write simply evaluate a binary number to decimal and if it is not zero then true else false.is this?
for e.g ob00000011 = 3 so it is true??
in your example for first case if complicated expression comes out to be true then??

Comment: @shafeeq yes exactly. It doesn't matter to what the complicated expression evaluates, because `0 & X == 0`, no matter what the value of `X` is.

Comment: u hanvt tell me that how a binary number is evaluated for true or false??

Comment: @shafeeq `0 => false` any thing else is `true`